# Crear options de acuerdo a valor ingresado en input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera saber como puedo crear optiones de un select de acuerdo a el numero que llene en un input, es decir que en mi input por defecto este con el 1 pero si yo le pongo 4 entonces mi select deberia de quedar asi

```html
<h4>COMO DEBERIA DE ESTAR INICIALMENTE</h4>
<input name="" id="" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="1">
<select id="opciones">
<option value="valor_1">valor 1</option>
</select>
<br>
<h4>COMO DEBERIA DE QUEDAR SI LLENO EL INPUT CON OTRO VALOR</h4>
<input name="" id="" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="4">
<select id="opciones">
<option value="valor_1">valor 1</option>
<option value="valor_1">valor 2</option>
<option value="valor_1">valor 3</option>
<option value="valor_1">valor 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: no tiene sentido que quieras usar el mismo **value** en más de un option, pues cualquiera que selecciones va a enviar lo mismo (a menos que lo que uses sea el texto del option con javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo primero, tienes que añadirle un "id" al input para que puedas referenciarlo en javascript. Una vez tienes eso, creas un evento "change" para que cuando cambie el valor del input, se ejecute el contenido de la función que rellenará el select. Primero lo vacias con el método `.empty()`, después simplemente creas un for desde 1 a la cantidad que hayas puesto en el input y vas añadiendo los option. Fíjate bien como te ha dicho @masterguru que el value debe variar para cada opción, no tiene sentido que le pongas el mismo value porque elijas lo que elijas en el select, siempre te devolvería el mismo valor.

Saludos.

```js
jQuery("#miinput").on("change", function() {
    var cantidad = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
    jQuery("#opciones").empty();
    for (i = 1; i <= cantidad; i++) {
        jQuery("#opciones").append('<option value="valor_' + i + '">valor ' + i + '</option>"');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="" id="miinput" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="1">
<select id="opciones">
<option value="valor_1">valor 1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: me funciono a la perfeccion gracias

Answer (score 0):

¿Algo asi?

```js
$("#num").keyup (function() {
   $("#opciones").html("");
   let html = "";
   let rep = parseInt ($(this).val())+1;
   for (i=1;i<rep;i++){
      html = html + `<option value="valor_1">valor ${i}</option>`
   }
   $("#opciones").html(html);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>select</h4>
<input name="" id="num" class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" value="1">
<select id="opciones">
<option value="valor_1">valor 1</option>
</select>
<br>
```